# Store app can't call MddBootstrapInitialize

Tags: winapi, uwp, winui-3

In my desktop app I successfully call MddBootstrapInitialize() to load the WinUI3 libraries which I can use them according to my article [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5359576/WinUI3-in-existing-Win32-applications).

When this app is published in the App Store, it's installed in a folder under `c:\program files\windowsapps`.

This time the call to MddBotstrapInitialize fails with ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED. If I move the files from the Store app folder anywhere else the call works.

Is there a way to resolve this? To package my app I use makemsix.exe pack -d ..\msix\out -p .\file.msix, where the out folder contains this AppxManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10" xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10" xmlns:uap10="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/10" xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities" IgnorableNamespaces="uap uap10 rescap">
    <!--Package created by MSIX Packaging Tool version: -->
    <Identity Name="..." Publisher="CN=..." Version="2.4808.0.0" ProcessorArchitecture="x64"/>
    <Properties>
        <DisplayName>...</DisplayName>
        <PublisherDisplayName>...</PublisherDisplayName>
        <Description>...</Description>
        <Logo>50x50.png</Logo>
        <uap10:PackageIntegrity>
            <uap10:Content Enforcement="on"/>
        </uap10:PackageIntegrity>
    </Properties>
    <Resources>
        <Resource Language="en-us"/>
    </Resources>
    <Dependencies>
        <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="10.0.17763.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.19041.1"/>
    </Dependencies>
    <Capabilities>
        <rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust"/>
    </Capabilities>
    <Applications>
        <Application Id="TPSixFour" Executable="tp64.exe" EntryPoint="Windows.FullTrustApplication">
            <uap:VisualElements BackgroundColor="transparent" DisplayName="..." Square150x150Logo="150x150.png" Square44x44Logo="44x44.png" Description="...">
                <uap:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="310x150.png" Square310x310Logo="310x310.png" Square71x71Logo="71x71.png"/>
            </uap:VisualElements>
        </Application>
    </Applications>
</Package>
```

Since the call to the bootstrap fails, can I tell the packager that I need and load the WinUI3 redistributable based on the XML?

Or, is there another way? Note that the call to the Bootstrap fails even if the app is run as administrator.

Comment: Have you tried `MddBootstrapInitialize2` with `MddBootstrapInitializeOptions_OnPackageIdentity_NOOP` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/win32/mddbootstrap/ne-mddbootstrap-mddbootstrapinitializeoptions

Comment: @SimonMourier I just tried. It succeeds, but later on I get class not registered errors. I have to call the bootstrap because the app executable isn't packaged itself.